# php ugrade error on ubuntu: packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: php, php5, ubuntu, apt

if I try to upgrade php on my vps with

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```

i get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-cli: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.6.1-1ubuntu10 is to be installed
            Depends: libdb4.8 but it is not installable
            Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libncurses5 (>= 5.7+20100313) but 5.6+20070716-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
            Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but 0.9.8e-5ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
            Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.6.30.dfsg-2ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

how can i solve it?

*edit with additional information:*
I added in my /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable all
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org/ stable all
```

and then run apt-get update

Comment: Do you have your package database updated?

Comment: just added some additional information to the question, thanks

Comment: why do you use debian stable packages when your tags say ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using the correct package sources.  You're obviously running Ubuntu (the versions of the packages you're running are a clear indication), but your `sources.list` is full of Debian stable packages.  That isn't going to work -- while Ubuntu is derived from Debian, their packages do not intermingle freely.

Replace the sources entries you quoted above with ones appropriate to your distribution, and your upgrade will go a lot smoother.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed some wrong instructions in a blog article. I read that my vps runs a gutsy version of ubuntu. To update php have I to add gutsy only packages or i can add natty ones?

Comment: If you want to upgrade Ubuntu, you'll need to.. upgrade Ubuntu.  Gutsy's hell-old, too; you've got quite a job ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that you have the right distro. Run:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

That will determine the release version you have. From there, when you pull the actual release name, follow the directions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine